# how to perform mouse on click action using threads

Tags: java, graphics

/* main- frame */

import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;

import javax.swing.* ;
public class Mainframe {

```
public Mainframe() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SimpleThread ST = new SimpleThread();
    ST.start();
}
```

}

/* simple thread */

import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;

import javax.swing.* ;
import java.lang.Thread.*;
class SimpleThread extends Thread {
    public SimpleThread() {
       // super(str);
    }
    public void run() {
     System.out.println("enter");

```
PaintDisp P= new PaintDisp();
P.init();
Mouseact MA= new Mouseact();
//MA.paint1();
//P.start();
 System.out.println(" mouse exits");
 System.out.println("exits");
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
 {
    //   Mouseact MA= new Mouseact();
        System.out.println("hi");

        try {
            sleep((int)(Math.random() * 10));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    System.out.println("DONE! " + getName());
}
```

}

/* paint disp */

import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;
import javax.swing.* ;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.lang.Thread.*;
public class PaintDisp extends Constants implements Runnable{

```
public void run(){init();   }   


        public void init(){
            setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            setSize((int)xpix,(int)ypix); 
            setUndecorated(true);
            show();

            }


                public void paint(Graphics g) { 
                //super(paint);
                    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
                    g.setColor( dackground );                       //  background color
                    g.fillRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );    //  To draw (xpix X ypix) Frame
                    g.setColor(Color.white);
                    g.drawRect( 1, 1, getWidth()-3, getHeight()-3 );        //  To Draw Outer most Rect
                    g.drawRect( (int)(meter_border[0]*adjx), (int)(meter_border[1]*adjy), (int)(meter_border[2]*adjx),(int)(meter_border[3]*adjy)); // Static Field Boarder     
                    g.drawRect(                         //System.out.println(":"+((int)(391*adjx))+":"+((int)(61*adjy))+":"+((getWidth()-401)*(int)adjx)+":"+((getHeight()-279)*(int)adjy));
                    // mainpower MP= new mainpower();
                        //  To Draw Outer most Rect
                    ReadTest1 RD= new ReadTest1();
                    RD.ReadTest2(g,g2);
                    RD.meterpointer(g, g2,pointerset);
                    Subsystem SB= new Subsystem();
                    SB.subsystem(g,g2,subsysystatus);
                     mainpower MP= new mainpower();
                     if(rect20Clicked){
                        // int scr1=1;
                            MP.screens(g,g2);
                            MP.screenescape(g,g2);
                            //rect20Clicked=true    ;
                     }

                        if(rect1Clicked ){
                            System.out.println(scrn);

                            MP.powercircuit(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);
                             }
                            //}
                        else if(rect5Clicked){
                            MP.TractionMotor(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);

                        }
                        else if(rect3Clicked){
                            MP.AuxiliaryConverter(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);

                        }
                        else if(rect7Clicked){
                            MP.HarmonicHotel(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);
        s                   
                        }
                        else if(rect9Clicked){
                            MP.AuxiliaryMachines(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);

                        }
                        else if(rect11Clicked){
                            MP.SubSystemIsolation(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);
                        }

                        else if(rect18Clicked){

                            System.out.println ("LOCO ="+LOCO);
                            MP.software_version(g,g2,locono);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);

                        }
                        else if(rect15Clicked){
                            MP.BrakeSystem(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);

                        }
                        else if(rect17Clicked){
                            MP.wheel_diameter(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);

                        }
                        else if(rect19Clicked){
                            MP.kmearned_enery(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);

                        }
                        else if(rect2Clicked){
                            MP.screens(g,g2);
                            MP.screenescape(g,g2);
                        }
                        else if(rect4Clicked){

                            MP.escape(g,g2);
                        }
                        else if(rect6Clicked){
                            MP.AuxiliaryMachines (g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);

                        }
                        else if(rect8Clicked){
                            MP.HarmonicHotel(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);

                        }
                        else if(rect10Clicked){

                            MP.escape(g,g2);
                        }
                        else if(rect25Clicked){
                            repaint();
                        }
                        else if(rect14Clicked){

                        }
                        else if(rect16Clicked){

                        }
                        else if(rect18Clicked){

                        }

                        else if(rect21Clicked){
                            MP.traction_braking(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);

                        }
                        else if(rect22Clicked){
                            MP.tempetature(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);
                        }
                        else if(rect23Clicked){
                            MP.oil_pressure(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);
                        }
                        else if(rect24Clicked){
                            MP.config_switches(g,g2);
                            MP.escape(g,g2);
                        }

            }


}
```

/* constants */

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;
import javax.swing.* ;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class Constants extends JFrame{

```
final double adjx   = 1;            // 
final double adjy   = 1;            //
final double xpix = 640*adjx;       // To Set the Frame X Resolution
final double ypix = 480*adjy;       // To Set the Frame Y Resolution

  int locodatax=280;
    int locodatay=29;
    int locodata_w=25;
    int locodata_h=30;


    final int CENTER_PIX_X = 320;           //  640   800
    final int CENTER_PIX_Y = 240-26;        //  480   600 -26 to shift meter up

    final int METER_X=470; // METER X COORDINATE    
    final int METER_Y=195;// METER Y COORDINATE
    final int RECT_W = 300;   // 310,to make equal partition
    final int RECT_H = 195;

    final int DEFAULT_SCREEN_X=5;
    final int DEFAULT_SCREEN_Y=62;
    final int DEFAULT_SCREEN_W=211;// 317 width
    final int DEFAULT_SCREEN_H=307;



    // variable that will be true when the user clicked i the rectangle 
    // the we will draw.

    /*----Display Resolution-----------*/

    int popwidth = 400;
    int pophight = 100;

    final int CENTER_OVEL_W = 25;//30
    final int CENTER_OVEL_H = 25;//30
    final int RADIOUS = 120; //260
    final int rad = ((RADIOUS-(RADIOUS/3))/2); // 90

    double half = RADIOUS/2;
    double base =(Math.sqrt((2*(half*half)))); 


    int  getWidth = 640;  // border width
    int  getHeight = 480;  // border height


    /* Driver Details*/

    int dix = 5;//15  ;driver x coordinate
    int diy = 8;//40  ; driver y coordinate 
    int diwidth = 627; //400 525  ; driver width
    int dihight = 20;  // driver height


    /*locono Date and Time Details*/
    final int loconox = 210; // locono table x coordinate
    final int loconoy = 68;  // locono table y coordinate
    final int locono_w = 225; // locono table width
    final int locono_h = 20;   // locono table height



        /* Sub system Details*/
    final int subx = 8; //  ;subsystem x coordinate
    final int suby =69; //  ;subsystem y coordinate
    final int sub_w = 32; //  ;subsystem width
    final int sub_h = 25; //  ;subsystem height


    /* screens details*/
    final int screens_border [] = { 219,61,412,309 };   
    final int screens_display [] = { 226,130,195,25 };  


    /* Mouse Actions*/

    int mainpowerx = 224;//219+27;//260
    int mainpowery=130;
    int mainpowerw=195;
    int mainpowerh = 25;
    int xpos=-10; int ypos=-10;
     int scr=0;
     int scr1=0;
    boolean mouseEntered;
boolean rect1Clicked;
    boolean rect2Clicked;
    boolean rect3Clicked;
    boolean rect4Clicked;
    boolean rect5Clicked;
    boolean rect6Clicked;
    boolean rect7Clicked;
    boolean rect8Clicked;
    boolean rect9Clicked;
    boolean rect10Clicked;
    boolean rect11Clicked;
    boolean rect12Clicked;
    boolean rect13Clicked;
    boolean rect14Clicked;
    boolean rect15Clicked;
    boolean rect16Clicked;
    boolean rect17Clicked;
    boolean rect18Clicked;
    boolean rect19Clicked;
    boolean rect20Clicked;
    boolean rect21Clicked;
    boolean rect22Clicked;
    boolean rect23Clicked;
    boolean rect24Clicked;
    boolean rect25Clicked;
    int scrn=0;
    int rect1xco = (int )((mainpowerx)*adjx);
    int rect1yco = (int )((mainpowery)*adjy);
    int rect1width = (int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect1height =(int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect3xco =(int )((mainpowerx)*adjx);
    int rect3yco = (int )((mainpowery+27)*adjy);
    int rect3width = (int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect3height =(int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect5xco = (int )((mainpowerx)*adjx);
    int rect5yco =(int )((mainpowery+54)*adjy);
    int rect5width = (int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect5height = (int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect7xco = (int )((mainpowerx)*adjx);
    int rect7yco = (int )((mainpowery+81)*adjy);
    int rect7width =(int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect7height = (int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);               //mainpowerx;

    int rect9xco = (int )((mainpowerx)*adjx);                   //mainpowery+108;
    int rect9yco =(int )((mainpowery+108)*adjy);
    int rect9width =(int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);                    //mainpowerw;
    int rect9height = (int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect11xco = (int )((mainpowerx)*adjx);
    int rect11yco = (int )((mainpowery+135)*adjy);
    int rect11width = (int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect11height = (int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect13xco = (int )((mainpowerx)*adjx);
    int rect13yco = (int )((mainpowery+162)*adjy);
    int rect13width = (int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect13height = (int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect15xco = (int )((mainpowerx+205)*adjx); 
    int rect15yco = (int )((mainpowery)*adjy);
    int rect15width = (int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect15height =(int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect17xco = (int )((mainpowerx+205)*adjx); 
    int rect17yco = (int )((mainpowery+108)*adjy);
    int rect17width =(int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect17height = (int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect18xco = (int )((mainpowerx+205)*adjx); 
    int rect18yco = (int )((mainpowery+162)*adjy);
    int rect18width =(int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect18height = (int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect19xco = (int )((mainpowerx+205)*adjx); 
    int rect19yco = (int )((mainpowery+135)*adjy);
    int rect19width =  (int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect19height =(int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect20xco = (int )((subx+38)*adjx);
    int rect20yco = (int )((suby+270)*adjy);//suby+270;
    int rect20width =(int )((sub_w)*adjx);
    int rect20height = (int )((sub_h)*adjy);

    int rect21xco = (int )((mainpowerx)*adjx); 
    int rect21yco = (int )((mainpowery+162)*adjy);
    int rect21width = (int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect21height = (int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect22xco = (int )((mainpowerx+205)*adjx); 
    int rect22yco = (int )((mainpowery+27)*adjy);
    int rect22width = (int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect22height =(int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect23xco = (int )((mainpowerx+205)*adjx); 
    int rect23yco =(int )((mainpowery+54)*adjy);
    int rect23width = (int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect23height = (int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect24xco = (int )((mainpowerx+205)*adjx); 
    int rect24yco =  (int )((mainpowery+81)*adjy);
    int rect24width =(int )((mainpowerw)*adjx);
    int rect24height = (int )((mainpowerh)*adjy);

    int rect2xco = (int )((575)*adjx); //575;
    int rect2yco =  (int )((65)*adjy);//65;
    int rect2width = (int )((50)*adjx); //50;
    int rect2height = (int )((20)*adjy);//20;

    int rect25xco = (int )((575)*adjx); //575;
    int rect25yco =  (int )((65)*adjy);//65;
    int rect25width = (int )((50)*adjx); //50;
    int rect25height = (int )((20)*adjy);//20;


Color dackground = new Color(0,0,0);
Color block = new Color(163,225,255,155);   // for Blue Gray Color
Color Green = new Color(102,255,153,255);   // for Green Color
Color Red = new Color(200,51,51,200);       // for Red Color
 Color Yellow = new Color(255,255,51);
Color Gray = new Color(161,161,161,205);    // for Gray Color
Color pantoback = new Color(61,61,61);      // for Panto Background Gray Color
Color line = new Color(224,224,224,55);     // for Panto Line
Color subcolor = new Color(31,31,31);       // for Subsysrem background Color
Color voltcurrentbackground = new Color(31,31,31,255);  // for voltage & Current Background
Color lightpink = new Color(253,204,255,50);


/*-------Main Screen all Squre Border ---------------*/
final int meter_border [] = { 391, 61 , 240, 201 };                     // Meter Border X , Y ,W ,H
final int static_field_border [] = { 220, 61, 168, 309 };               // Static Field Boarder X, Y, W ,H
final int battery_border [] = { 391, 266, 78, 104 };                    // Battery Boarder X , Y ,W ,H
final int auto_brake_pressure_border [] = { 472, 266, 78, 104 };        // Auto Brake Pressure X , Y ,W ,H
final int line_frequency_border [] = { 553, 266, 78, 104 };             // Line Frequency Boarder X , Y ,W ,H
final int default_screen [] = { 5, 61, 212, 309 };                      // Default_screen   X , Y ,W ,H 
final int lcd_Boarder [] = { 331, 373, 300, 100};                       // LCD Boarder
final int screen_button []={42,336,37,29};                              // screen button  X,Y,W,H
/* ---------Driver Details------------------------*/
final int driver_info [] = { 10, 18, 627, 18 };     // Driver INFO X1 ,Y1, X2, Y2
final int stno  = 3;                                // Station number Display on screen 
int st = 0;
final int diff = ((int)(585*adjx))/(stno-1);        // Each Station Diference       
int stdiff = 0;                 
final int trpos = 4;                                // Position of the Train
int trdiff = 0;

/*---------loconodatetime, Panto UpDown, VCB, Brake Applied------------*/
```

//  final String LOCO_NO = "E:\Pratibha\eprog\workspace\Driver Display1.2\src\loco no.txt";
    FileInputStream fin;
    String locono ="XXXXX ";
    String LOCO;
    public static String dt;
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss";

```
final int loconodatetime [] = { 5, 29, 627, 30 };   // loconodatetime X Y W H

final int locodata [] ={ 280, 29, 25, 30 };         // For Panto VCB Brake MR Pressure

int pantoupdown = 1;                                // Run Time Variable
int vbconoff = 1;                                   // Run Time Variable
int brakeapp = 1;
/* ----------------Sub system Details------------------*/

final int subw = 32;
final int subh = 25;
final int subsystem[][] = { { 8,  68, subw, subh },/*for SS01*/ {  44,  68, subw, subh },/* for SS02*/
                            { 8,  98, subw, subh },/*for SS03*/ {  44,  98, subw, subh },/* for SS04*/
                            { 8, 128, subw, subh },/*for SS05*/ {  44, 128, subw, subh },/* for SS06*/ 
                            { 8, 158, subw, subh },/*for SS07*/ {  44, 158, subw, subh },/* for SS08*/
                            { 8, 188, subw, subh },/*for SS09*/ {  44, 188, subw, subh },/* for SS10*/
                            { 8, 218, subw, subh },/*for SS11*/ {  44, 218, subw, subh },/* for SS12*/ 
                            { 8, 248, subw, subh },/*for SS13*/ {  44, 248, subw, subh },/* for SS14*/
                            { 8, 278, subw, subh },/*for SS15*/ {  44, 278, subw, subh },/* for SS16*/
                            { 8, 308, subw, subh },/*for SS17*/ {  44, 308, subw, subh },/* for SS18*/ 
                            { 8, 338, subw, subh },/*for SS19*/ {  44, 338, subw, subh },/* for SS20*/

                            };              //  1 - 19 subsystem  X Y W H   

String subsystem_string [] =    {"SS01","SS02","SS03","SS04","SS05","SS06","SS07","SS08","SS09","SS10",
                                "SS11","SS12","SS13","SS14","SS15","SS16","SS17","SS18","SS19","    "
                                };

int [] substatus = new int [20];        //  subsystem Run Time Variable
int subsysystatus = 1;                  //  Run Time Variable

/*--------------------------Voltage and Current bar Details------------------------*/
```

//----------------SCREEN DETAILS--------------------------

//   final int screens_border [] = { 219, 61, 412, 309 };   // Screen Border X Y W H
//   final int screens_display [] = { 226, 130, 195, 25 };  // Screen Inner Blocks X Y W H
     final int screens_row [] = {97,124,151,178,205,232,259,286,313,340};// Inner Blocks Y Coordinates
     final int mainpowercol [] = {5,206};   // Col 1 and 2 X Coordinates
     String str ;
     int len = 0;

```
 /*----------------traction_braking---------------------*/
 String traction_braking_header [] = {"TRACTION & BRAKING"};
 String traction_braking_string [] = {"Active CAB","MSC Node","Throttle Zero","Constant Speed Mode","Pressure Auto Brake Line","TE/BE","Bogie 1","Bogie 2","Loco","Demand","Actual"};
 String traction_braking_onoff []  = {"ON","OFF"};
 String cab[] = {"1","2"};          // Active Cab 1 or 2

 int [] traction_braking_int = new int [1];             // Run Time Variable MSC Node
 double [] traction_braking_float = new double[15];     // Run Time Variable 

 int cab1or2 = 1;                   // Run Time Variable
 int throttle_zero = 0;             // Run Time Variable
 int con_speed_mode = 1;            // Run Time Variable

 /*---------------------Temperatures------------------------*/

 String tempetature_header [] = {"TEMPERATURES"};
 String tempetature_string [] = {"I/P Power","Traction Converter","Transformer","SR1","SR2","TFP1","TFP2","Traction Motors","TM1","TM2","TM3","TM4","TM5","TM6"};
 double [] tempetature_float = new double[15];          // Run Time Variable 

 /*---------------------Oil Pressure------------------------*/

 String oil_pressure_header [] = {"OIL PRESSURE"};
```

//   String oil_pressure_string [] = {"I/P Power","Traction Converter","Transformer","SR1","SR2","TFP1","TFP2"};
     double [] oil_pressure_float = new double [10];        // Run Time Variable

```
 /*---------------------config_switches------------------------*/

 String configswitches_header [] = {"CONFIG  SWITCHES"};
 String configswitches_string [] = {"TE Limit"," Banking","Fail Mode","BG1 Out","BG2 Out","Fail Mode","Simulation","Configuration"};

 int telimit=1;                     // Run Time Variable
 int banking=0;                     // Run Time Variable    
 int failmode=1;                    // Run Time Variable                
 int bg1out=0;                      // Run Time Variable        
 int bg2out=1;                      // Run Time Variable
 int simulation=0;                  // Run Time Variable        
 int configuration=1;               // Run Time Variable

 /*--------------------wheel_diameter-----------------------*/   

 String wheeldiameter_header[] = {"WHEEL DIAMETERS"};
 String wheeldiameter_string[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12", };
 double [] wheeldiameter_float = new double [12];    

/*---------------- kmearned_enery---------------------------*/

 String kmenergy_header[] = {"KM EARNED AND ENERGY"};
 String kmenergy_string [] = {"Km Earned","GWh","MWh","kWh","Energy Consumed","Energy Regenerated","% of Regenerated"};         

 double [] kmenergy_float = new double [15];    // Run Time Variable
 String [] kmenergy_unit = new String [5];      // Run Time Variable

 /*------------------software version------------------------*/     

 String s_v_header[] = { "Software Version" };
 String s_v_string[] = {"LOCO TYPE","FLG 1","FLG 2","HBB 1","HBB 2","STB 1","STB 2","SLG 1","SLG 2"};   // for LOCO TYPE

 String [] s_v_unit = new String [15];
 double [] s_v_float = new double [10];     // Run Time Variable
```

}

/*mouse act*/
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;

import javax.swing.* ;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Thread.*;

public class Mouseact extends Constants {

```
public Mouseact() {
//   System.out.println("mouse event starts");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent me) {
            System.out.println("mouse event starts");
            //Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
            // Save the coordinates of the click lke this.
            xpos = me.getX();
            ypos = me.getY();
            System.out.println("mouse event starts");
             for (int j=0;j<10;j++){
                 System.out.println("mouse event starts");
             }
            // Check if the click was inside the rectangle area.
            if(xpos > rect20xco && xpos < rect20xco+rect20width && ypos >rect20yco && ypos < rect20yco+rect20height) 
            {
                rect20Clicked = true;
                System.out.println("rect20="+rect20Clicked);
                scrn++;
                scrn=1;
                repaint();

                //int scr=1;
                //return true;



            }
            else 
                    {
                rect20Clicked = false;
        repaint();
    //  return false;
                }
//      }
```

//      }
//  public void mouseClicked1 (MouseEvent me) {
                if (xpos > rect1xco && xpos < rect1xco+rect1width && ypos >rect1yco && ypos < rect1yco+rect1height)

```
            {   rect1Clicked = true;


                repaint();

            }


            else 
                rect1Clicked = false;
        repaint();


            // if it was not then rect1Clicked  is false;
              if(xpos > rect3xco && xpos < rect3xco+rect3width && ypos >rect3yco && ypos < rect3yco+rect3height) 
                rect3Clicked = true;
            else 
                rect3Clicked = false;
        repaint();
            //show the results  of the click
            if(xpos > rect25xco && xpos < rect25xco+rect3width && ypos >rect25yco && ypos < rect25yco+rect25height) 
                rect25Clicked = true;
            else 
                rect25Clicked = false;
    repaint();

            if(xpos > rect5xco && xpos < rect5xco+rect3width && ypos >rect5yco && ypos < rect5yco+rect5height) 
                rect5Clicked = true;
            else 
                rect5Clicked = false;
        repaint();
            if(xpos > rect7xco && xpos < rect7xco+rect7width && ypos >rect7yco && ypos < rect7yco+rect7height) 
                rect7Clicked = true;
            else 
                rect7Clicked = false;
        repaint();
            if(xpos > rect9xco && xpos < rect9xco+rect9width && ypos >rect9yco && ypos < rect9yco+rect9height) 
                rect9Clicked = true;
            else 
                rect9Clicked = false;
            repaint();
            if(xpos > rect11xco && xpos < rect11xco+rect11width && ypos >rect11yco && ypos < rect11yco+rect11height) 
                rect11Clicked = true;
            else 
                rect11Clicked = false;
        repaint();
             if(xpos > rect18xco && xpos < rect18xco+rect18width && ypos >rect18yco && ypos < rect18yco+rect18height) 
                    rect18Clicked = true;
                else 
                    rect18Clicked = false;
            repaint();
                //show the results  of the click

                if(xpos > rect15xco && xpos < rect15xco+rect15width && ypos >rect15yco && ypos < rect15yco+rect15height) 
                    rect15Clicked = true;
                else 
                    rect15Clicked = false;
        repaint();
                if(xpos > rect17xco && xpos < rect17xco+rect17width && ypos >rect17yco && ypos < rect17yco+rect17height) 
                    rect17Clicked = true;
                else 
                    rect17Clicked = false;
                repaint();
                if(xpos > rect19xco && xpos < rect19xco+rect19width && ypos >rect19yco && ypos < rect19yco+rect19height) 
                    rect19Clicked = true;
                else 
                    rect19Clicked = false;
            repaint();


                if(xpos > rect21xco && xpos < rect21xco+rect21width && ypos >rect21yco && ypos < rect21yco+rect21height) 
                    rect21Clicked = true;
                else 
                    rect21Clicked = false;
            repaint();
                if(xpos > rect22xco && xpos < rect22xco+rect22width && ypos >rect22yco && ypos < rect22yco+rect22height) 
                    rect22Clicked = true;
                else 
                    rect22Clicked = false;
                repaint();

                if(xpos > rect23xco && xpos < rect23xco+rect23width && ypos >rect23yco && ypos < rect23yco+rect23height) 
                    rect23Clicked = true;
                else 
                    rect23Clicked = false;
            repaint();

                if(xpos > rect24xco && xpos < rect24xco+rect24width && ypos >rect24yco && ypos < rect24yco+rect24height) 
                    rect24Clicked = true;
                else 
                    rect24Clicked = false;
        repaint();

                if(xpos > rect2xco && xpos < rect2xco+rect2width && ypos >rect2yco && ypos < rect2yco+rect2height) 
                    rect2Clicked = true;
                else 
                    rect2Clicked = false;
        repaint();

        }

public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me) {}

        // When it has been released
        // not that a click also calls these Mouse-Pressed and Released.
        // since they are empty nothing hapens here.
        public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent me) {}    

        // This is executed when the mouse enters the applet. it will only
        // be executed again when the mouse has left and then re-entered.
    public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent me) {
            // Will draw the "inside applet message"
            mouseEntered = true;
            repaint();
        }

        // When the Mouse leaves the applet.
    public void mouseExited (MouseEvent me) {
            // will draw the "outside applet message
            mouseEntered = false;
            repaint();
        }   


}
```

);

```
}
/*public void paint1(){
    show();
}*/
public void paint(Graphics g) { 
    //super(paint);
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(230,75,40,40);
         mainpower MP= new mainpower();
         if(rect20Clicked){
            // int scr1=1;
                MP.screens(g,g2);
                MP.screenescape(g,g2);
                //rect20Clicked=true    ;
         }

            if(rect1Clicked ){
                System.out.println(scrn);

                MP.powercircuit(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);
                 }
                //}
            else if(rect5Clicked){
                MP.TractionMotor(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);

            }
            else if(rect3Clicked){
                MP.AuxiliaryConverter(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);

            }
            else if(rect7Clicked){
                MP.HarmonicHotel(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);

            }
            else if(rect9Clicked){
                MP.AuxiliaryMachines(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);

            }
            else if(rect11Clicked){
                MP.SubSystemIsolation(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);
            }

            else if(rect18Clicked){

                System.out.println ("LOCO ="+LOCO);
                MP.software_version(g,g2,locono);
                MP.escape(g,g2);

            }
            else if(rect15Clicked){
                MP.BrakeSystem(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);

            }
            else if(rect17Clicked){
                MP.wheel_diameter(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);

            }
            else if(rect19Clicked){
                MP.kmearned_enery(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);

            }
            else if(rect2Clicked){
                MP.screens(g,g2);
                MP.screenescape(g,g2);
            }
            else if(rect4Clicked){

                MP.escape(g,g2);
            }
            else if(rect6Clicked){
                MP.AuxiliaryMachines (g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);

            }
            else if(rect8Clicked){
                MP.HarmonicHotel(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);

            }
            else if(rect10Clicked){

                MP.escape(g,g2);
            }
            else if(rect25Clicked){
                repaint();
            }
            else if(rect14Clicked){

            }
            else if(rect16Clicked){

            }
            else if(rect18Clicked){

            }

            else if(rect21Clicked){
                MP.traction_braking(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);

            }
            else if(rect22Clicked){
                MP.tempetature(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);
            }
            else if(rect23Clicked){
                MP.oil_pressure(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);
            }
            else if(rect24Clicked){
                MP.config_switches(g,g2);
                MP.escape(g,g2);
            }

}
```

}

Comment: ... I tried to reformat the post but indenting the code exceeded the char limit of 30.000. Never had *that* before.

Comment: If you ask a question, try to post just the code that is relevant for the problem you have. This will probably also make it easier for yourself to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Swing is developed so that, in general, only one thread sparks events and updates the UI.  There are exceptions though.  I don't completely get what your asking, bur here is documentation on adding a [mouse listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html), and here is documentation on [threading in Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html).

On mouse click, you can spawn off a thread if you need to.  Be careful though, threading can get heavy, and complex fast.